# extra query needed for resource not found?

Tags: rest, clickhouse

I am writing this API `/trace/{{id}}/spans?span_kind=server`. This is gonna fetch all the spans which are having span_kind=server.

If particular {{id}} is not present in database, we should throw 404.
If we give one SQL/Clickhouse query to retrieve the spans of a traceId and it gives empty results there may be 2 chances.

1. None of the spans have span_kind=server [which is 200 with[]]
2. TraceId is not present in DB [which is 404 error]

Could n't differentiate the 404 with this query so extra query is needed to check traceId is present or not.
But that is performance hit. Any other thoughts please share